# Drag & drop swap div places

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm doing a drag and drop inventory for a point-and-click game. The inventory is set up and when an item is dropped in a slot it answers to that place.

Two items can at present time be in the same slot, which is not ideal. 
1. What I want is that when an item inside the inventory is dropped on an already occupied slot, the items should switch places with one another.
And 2. When an item outside of the inventory is dropped inside it should land in the first open slot.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.item').draggable({
        accept: ".item",
        containment: '#container', 
        cursor: 'pointer',
        revert: function(is_valid_drop){
                console.log("is_valid_drop = " + is_valid_drop);
                if(!is_valid_drop){
                   console.log("revert triggered");
                   return true;
                } else {
                    //Annat
                }
            }
        });

    $('.slot').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = width / 2 - ui.draggable.width() / 2;
            var cntrTop = height / 2 - ui.draggable.height() / 2;

            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="item" id="key"></div>
        <div class="item" id="key2"></div>

        <div id="inventory">
            <div class="slot"></div>
            <div class="slot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* GENERAL STYLE */
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:667px;
    height:375px;
    background-color:#999;
}


/* GENERAL BUTTONS SETTINGS */


/* STYLE */
/* GENERAL ITEM SETTINGS */
.item{
    position:absolute;
}
/* ITEM IDs AND THEIR STYLING */
#key, #key2{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:10;
}
#key{
    background-color:gold;
    left:230px;
    top:100px;
}
#key2{
    background-color:silver;
    left:252px;
    top:100px;
}
#inventory{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    z-index:1;
}
.slot{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    width:78px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got you right...

- **Drag and drop** an item to the inventory.
- **Prepended** dropped item *to the existing inventory items list*
- **Sort inventory** item list to have the newly dropped item at the top, displace the other items 1 step down

Comment: The drag and drop part is already set. The sorting should switch places with the items already inside the inventory. And the outside item should land in the next free slot. So if slot 1 is occupied, the new item should land in slot 2.